# how to find application that is opening proccesses

Tags: processes

When running `ps` as root within my device (HTC Desire HD)
I see the following line:

```
app_132   18584 13586 0      0     ffffffff 00000000 Z ratc
```

Repeating hundreds of times.

How can I tell which app is "app_132" ?

UPDATE:
O.k. I actually found out which app it was based on the class names listed at the end of first lines in the output of the ps command where app_132 is listed.

```
ps | grep app_132 | more
```

but even though this solves my immediate situation I still would like an answer to the original Q.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers in "app_XYZ" name will be different on every device, since they depend on the order of installed apps.

In adb shell or terminal emulator perform the following command:

```
ls -l /data/data/
```

This should return a listing of installed apps' directories that contain their data and settings, like so:

```
drwxr-x--x app_1    app_1             2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.backupconfirm
drwxr-x--x app_2    app_2             2012-04-04 09:37 com.android.bluetooth
drwxr-x--x app_3    app_3             2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.browser
drwxr-x--x app_4    app_4             2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.calculator2
drwxr-x--x app_5    app_5             2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.calendar
drwxr-x--x app_7    app_7             2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.camera
drwxr-x--x app_8    app_8             2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.certinstaller
drwxr-x--x app_70   app_70            2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.chrome
drwxr-x--x app_0    app_0             2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.contacts
drwxr-x--x app_10   app_10            2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.defcontainer
drwxr-x--x app_11   app_11            2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.deskclock
drwxr-x--x app_12   app_12            2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.development
drwxr-x--x app_14   app_14            2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.email
drwxr-x--x app_15   app_15            2012-03-28 09:07 com.android.exchange
```

The 2nd and 3rd columns list the app's owner, while the 5th column contains the app's package name.  Find the line corresponding to the "app_132" from your logcat entry, and the package name will help you figure out the responsible app.

Once you have the package name, try searching for it in the Google Play Store.  Just use the link `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xxxxxxx`, where "xxxxxxx" is the package name you found.  For example, on my phone "app_70" corresponds to "com.android.chrome", which corresponds to Google Chrome browser in the Play Store: [`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome)

Comment: Thank you for a great answer.
maybe you can help with my other android Q (about readonly file system...)

Comment: using `ls -l /data/data/ | grep app_XXX` is even better :)